# LinkedIn JS API - can't get educations object via JS

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I have a problem with LinkedIn JS API. Everything is configured and works fine when i run app and i **have** access to:

```
IN.API.Connections("me")
    .fields("id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl")
    .result(function(result, metadata) {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

but when i try to get educations, languages or others collections i **cant get it**.

Following code returns for me an empty object:

```
IN.API.Connections("me")
    .fields("educations")
    .result(function(result, metadata) {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

I've tried everything. Please give me some help.

Ps.
When i use [apigee.com](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) or [JavaScript API Developer Console](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console/) there is no issue.

Comment: Are you specifying the [member permissions](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)? You would need the `r_fullprofile` permissions to get the educations values.

Comment: @PaulMennega yes i have r_fullprofile and r_network

Comment: When you are authing the user, does the auth window explicitly state that you are asking for full profile, network permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get information about your connections, you can only get Basic Profile fields of 1st degree connections.

Here is the list of profile fields: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile. Educations is not one of the basic profile fields.